# Why slash in dictionary have a wrong amount?

Tags: python, dictionary, os.path

```
import os
print(os.path.abspath("test1/test"))
print({1: os.path.abspath("test1/test")})
```

---

D:\ZTK\autotest\Learn\test1\test 
{1: 'D:\ZTK\autotest\Learn\test1\test'}

Answer (score 0):

both are exactly the same, what do you mean ?

```
>>> a = os.path.abspath("test1/test")
>>> b = {1: os.path.abspath("test1/test")}
>>> a == b[1]
True
```